# Difference between sklearn shuffle and np.random.permutation

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, shuffle

What is the difference between doing:

```
idx = np.random.permutation(len(X))
x,y = X[idx], labels[idx]
```

and

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
x, y = shuffle(X, labels)
```

to shuffle a dataset? Thank you

Comment: What kind of an answer are you expecting to this question? One method uses one function, another uses a different function. They both do the same thing, more or less.

Comment: Note: `shuffle` is an alias of `resample`, so if you want to compare their implementations have a look at its definition in the sklearn codebase.